Place to buy Modern Orthodox Gedolim pictures?
Is there a place online to buy pictures of Modern Orthodox Jewish leaders ("Gedolim") such as Rav Soloveitchik, Rav Lichtenstein, Rav Amital, Rabbi Jonathan Sacks, and Nechama Leibowitz?

I could not find any for sale even in Judaica stores in modern orthodox communities, perhaps these just do not exist?

Do searches like joseph soloveitchik paintings for sale not give you some options?

Can you just find a picture online and send it to walgreens?

https://rabbisacks.org/videos/on-modern-orthodoxy/

I dont believe  Rav Soloveitchik would consider himself the leader of Modern orthodox

You can buy here pictures of Rabbi Chaim Druckman: https://machon.oretzion.com/%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%96%D7%A6%D7%9C

There are portraits of the Rav here and here.
Here is one of Rav Lichtenstein.
Here is one of Nechama Leibowitz.
Here is one of Rav Sacks.
But it seems there is no business organized around the theme of “Modern Orthodox Gedolim pictures.”

Agreed on that it's not a business. Reminds me of this joke: "I walked into the bookstore and asked where to find the self-help books. The clerk just shook her head and said that would defeat the point..."

excellent joke
